# Filter/select a javascript Objects by an Array content

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to filter these Javascript objects:

```
   A= [{
      asset_bubble: 17,
      biodiversity_loss: 15,
      code: "CH",
      critical_information: 14,
      cyber_attacks: 19,
      data_fraud: 13,
      deflation: 4,
      energy: 18,
      extreme_weather: 12,
      change_adaptation: 9,
      infrastructure: 33
   },
   {
     asset_bubble: 4,
     biodiversity_loss: 7,
     code: "TZ"
     critical_information: 9,
     cyber_attacks: 9,
     data_fraud: 10,
     deflation: 3,
     energy: 1,
     extreme_weather: 2,
     change_adaptation: 7
     infrastructure: 3
}]
```

By this array:

```
array=["data_fraud","change_adaptation", "deflation","code"]
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
B= [{     code: "CH",
          data_fraud: 13,
          deflation: 4,
          change_adaptation: 9
       },
       {
         code: "TZ"
         data_fraud: 10,
         deflation: 3,
         change_adaptation: 7
    }]
```

I have done this:

```
B = A.map(({ ...array }) => ({ ...array }))
```

But this is not working. I know map should do the work but how can I list the fields of the objects I want to filter out?

Comment: You could use `array.filter` to filter instead of `map`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, yes whatever works. Though I thought map would be best

Comment: Map doesn't filter though. That's what filter does. --- Sorry I think I misread. You want to keep the same array size, but remove properties from each item object?

Comment: Actually you do want `map` here, because you want an array of the same length with transformed objects.

Comment: Basically I wand to keep the fields that are in the array

Comment: The B function is close. Return an object that has the properties you would like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `Array.map` callback, you can map `array` variable values to `[key, item[key]]` pair and from that 2d array, you can generate the object using `Object.fromEntries` as follows.

```js
const A = [{
  asset_bubble: 17,
  biodiversity_loss: 15,
  code: "CH",
  critical_information: 14,
  cyber_attacks: 19,
  data_fraud: 13,
  deflation: 4,
  energy: 18,
  extreme_weather: 12,
  change_adaptation: 9,
  infrastructure: 33
}, {
  asset_bubble: 4,
  biodiversity_loss: 7,
  code: "TZ",
  critical_information: 9,
  cyber_attacks: 9,
  data_fraud: 10,
  deflation: 3,
  energy: 1,
  extreme_weather: 2,
  change_adaptation: 7,
  infrastructure: 3
}];

const array = ["data_fraud","change_adaptation", "deflation","code"];

const B = A.map((item) => (
  Object.fromEntries(array.map((key) => ([key, item[key]])))
));
console.log(B);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach, using `reduce`:

```js
const A= [ {
      asset_bubble: 17,
      biodiversity_loss: 15,
      code: "CH",
      critical_information: 14,
      cyber_attacks: 19,
      data_fraud: 13,
      deflation: 4,
      energy: 18,
      extreme_weather: 12,
      change_adaptation: 9,
      infrastructure: 33
   },
   {
     asset_bubble: 4,
     biodiversity_loss: 7,
     code: "TZ",
     critical_information: 9,
     cyber_attacks: 9,
     data_fraud: 10,
     deflation: 3,
     energy: 1,
     extreme_weather: 2,
     change_adaptation: 7,
     infrastructure: 3
}];

const array=["data_fraud","change_adaptation", "deflation","code"];

const B = A.map(item => array.reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: item[key]}), {}));

console.log(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
B = A.map(({ code, data_fraud, deflation, change_adaptation }) => ({ code, data_fraud, deflation, change_adaptation }))
```

I think this should work?

Comment: yes it does, but only because you've hard-coded the fields to keep. This won't work if `array` can be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

based on Derek's answer I made handy function to filter object by its keys:

```
function filterBykeys ( target, keyList ) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(target).filter(
      ([key,value]) => keyList.includes(key)
    )
  )
}
```

and here is a snippet using this function

```js
function filterBykeys ( target, keyList ) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(target).filter(
      ([key,value]) => keyList.includes(key)
    )
  )
}

const data= [{
      asset_bubble: 17,
      biodiversity_loss: 15,
      code: "CH",
      critical_information: 14,
      cyber_attacks: 19,
      data_fraud: 13,
      deflation: 4,
      energy: 18,
      extreme_weather: 12,
      change_adaptation: 9,
      infrastructure: 33
   },
   {
     asset_bubble: 4,
     biodiversity_loss: 7,
     code: "TZ",
     critical_information: 9,
     cyber_attacks: 9,
     data_fraud: 10,
     deflation: 3,
     energy: 1,
     extreme_weather: 2,
     change_adaptation: 7,
     infrastructure: 3
}];

const arrays=["data_fraud","change_adaptation", "deflation","code"];

const result = data.map( obj => {
  return filterBykeys(obj, arrays);
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This only returns the keys.